# What's the best way to track how long a video has been watched?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I would like to make a database entry if a certain amount of the video has been watched without having the person be able to skip to the end of the clip to reap the benefits.

Essentially, I am looking for a method that stores the amount of seconds/minutes that have been watched. And then I would just check it against the total duration of the video and I would have the percentage.

Unfortunately, the current way I use just tells me the total percentage of the current time of the movie. I cant find the correct way to do this.

```
$("#content_video").on("timeupdate", function() {
  var current_time = this.currentTime;

  var percentage = current_time * 100 / this.duration;
  console.log("Video played "+ percentage +"%");
});
```

How can I have find the total percentage watched?

Thanks so much!

Comment: How do you intend to count (or not) time spent watching the same section of a video repeatedly? That is: how do you want to account for the viewer skipping back in time? There's no right or wrong answer here.

Comment: True. Is there any way to track such behavior of counting the time spent watching, though, no matter whether it is a repeated section watched or not?